# How to slide page when link is clicked in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

Basically I have a page scrolling website and I want to scroll the page when a link is pressed. This is my html so far:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="inner">
        <div id="home">
            <button>Click</button>
            <div class = "Category_Menu_Container">
                <a class ="menu_Items" href="" >+ Events</a> 
                <a class ="menu_Items" href="" >+ News</a> 
                <a class ="menu_Items" href="" >+ Info</a> 
                <a class ="menu_Items" href="" >+ Sports</a> 
            </div>
            <p> Choose a Category </p>
        </div>
        <div id="Events_Page">
            <button>Click</button>
        </div>
        <div id="News_Page">
            <button>Click</button>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

This is my jquery:

```
function toggleDivs() {
    var $inner = $("#inner");

    // See which <divs> should be animated in/out.
    if ($inner.position().left == 0) {
        $inner.animate({
            left: "-100%"
        });
    }
    else {
        $inner.animate({
            left: "0px"
        });
    }

}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu_Items').bind("click", function() {
        alert("Got here");
    });

    $("button").bind("click", function() {
        toggleDivs();
    });
 });
```

This doesn't work when i click the Events link or whatever link, only works for the "click" Button, i want to be able to click any of the link to go to the next view not just the click me. Thanks alot guys !!!!

Answer (score 0):

try to change this:

```
$("button").bind("click", function() {
    toggleDivs();
});
```

to this:

```
$(document).on("click", "button", function() {
    toggleDivs();
});
```

if button aren't created dynamically you can do more easily:

```
$("button").click(function() {
   toggleDivs();
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

same thing for hyperlinks:

```
$(document).on("click", ".menu_Items", function() {
        alert("Got here");
    });
```

or more easily:

```
$(".menu_Items").click(function() {
   alert("Got here");
});
```

Comment: this will only work for the "click" button i guess, i want it to work for the hyperlinks aswell, how do i do that? thanks alot !

Comment: They are already there, "Events", "News", "Info", "Sports" with the anchor tags, when i click those, nothing happens !